# scalable windows in os x

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i'm trying to create a window that can be scaled, just like the iPhone/iPad simulator.  in the iPad simulator, you can select Window > Scale and select either 100% or 50%.

is there a way to make an `NSWindow` do this?  i've looked at applying `scaleUnitSquareToSize` to the window's `contentView` but no matter what i do in InterfaceBuilder, the contentView keeps resizing itself to fill the window.  is this the correct behavior even after removing all struts for the contentView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great open source implementation of a zoomable NSView:[GCZoomView](http://apptree.net/gczoomview.htm)

> the contentView keeps resizing itself
>   to fill the window

The content view's autoresizing behavior has nothing to do with the unit square's scale factor.